# TextView displaying text all the time

Tags: android

I want my text object to show string in TextView after the complete execution of for loop in startGame() function, but it is displaying the TextView as soon as it enters the startGame() function. I don't know may be this is out of order execution or what, but can anyone please help me?

Here is my code:
`
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

```
public class EasyGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

private int counter;
private TextView text;
private boolean flag = false;
private Button button = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy_game);

startGame();
}

public void startGame()
{
counter = 3;
int temp;
int i;
int level = 1;
long nanoSec = 0;
final Random rand = new Random();
Timer timer = new Timer();


while(true)
{
BinaryTree binaryTree = new BinaryTree(counter);
nanoSec = 2000;

for(i = 0; i<counter; ++i)
{
temp = rand.nextInt(4);

switch(temp)
{
case 0:
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);   break;

case 1:
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);   break;

case 2:
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);   break;

case 3:
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);   break;
}

timer.schedule(new MyTask(button, temp), nanoSec);
timer.schedule(new MyTask(button, -1), nanoSec + 500);

nanoSec += 2000;
binaryTree.insert(temp);

}

text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.levelText);
text.setText("Level: " + level);

break;
}


}



class MyTask extends TimerTask
{
private Button buttonId;
private int buttonNumb;

public MyTask(Button buttonId, int temp)
{
super();
this.buttonId = buttonId;
buttonNumb = temp;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run()
{
if(buttonNumb == -1)
{
buttonId.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}

else if(buttonNumb == 0)
{
buttonId.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}


else if(buttonNumb == 1)
{
buttonId.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

}

else if(buttonNumb == 2)
{
buttonId.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}


else if(buttonNumb == 3)
{
buttonId.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
}
});
}
}

}
```

`

here is my xml File: 
`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/levelText"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textSize="50dp"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:text = "" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countDnText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="100dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text=""
    />


<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="79dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`

Comment: how do you make sure it updates textview immediate after entering the for loop but not after completion of it ? Through logs ? counter value is just 3 so should not it be very quick that you can not even notice ?

Comment: I assume the issue is that your TextView is getting updated before the button colors are changed in the TimerTask. The reason this is happening is because when you schedule a Timer, it does not block the execution flow, but instead adds the TimerTask to a queue to be ran on a separate thread after the specified timeout. So all of your timers would be scheduled within ~10ms, the TextView would be updated, and then your first scheduled Timer would execute (after 2000 ms if I'm reading correctly).

Comment: so what should I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will not wait for the timer to complete before setting the text of the textview, so it is working something like this (arbitrary ms values to make my point):

- 0ms - Run through For Loop, queue up timers - run first timer (@ nanoSecond = 0)
- 10ms - Set TextView Text
- 500ms - second Task fires (@ nanoSecond = 500)
- etc. for other For loop items.

You can simply set the edit text to happen on a timer like you have each task (@nanoSecond) and it will enqueue after the other tasks. Something like this should work (replacing your current TextView code).

```
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.levelText);
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        textView.setText("Level: " + level);
    }
}, nanoSec);
```